# Is conditional r-squared ever zero?

Tags: multiple-regression, r-squared, autoregressive

I am using multivariate auto regressive modeling (MAR) to assess a complex data set (MAR is a form of vector auto regressive modeling, VAR). The output of the MAR method is >1 response variables and >1 explanatory variables. I'm using the R package MAR1, which outputs the best models according to AIC.

My problem is that for some response variables, there are no explanatory variables at all retained by the model (i.e. all coefficients are zero). This results in an r-squared of zero, but the conditional r-squared is non-zero. Is this an error in the software, or is it possible to have a conditional r-squared of non-zero under these conditions? And if it is possible, is there an intuitive explanation for this?

Below I show a fake MAR model to illustrate what I mean. The numbers in the cells are the coefficients. (The response variables are at time *t* and the explanatory variables are at *t*-1.)

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I asked the package author who said that the non-zero r-squared in the absence of coefficients was an error.